# Disable placeholder text to be read by all accessibility API(screen reader)

Tags: html, input, accessibility, placeholder

Some screen readers read placeholder value and some do not. Is there a way in which reading placeholder value can be disabled for All screen reader(in context with HTML input). Especially the IOS screen reader reads placeholder value, in that case, the same information repeated twice.

What I want is to show placeholders for screen users and hidden labels for screen reader users.

Edit: When I asked the question it was the first time working on accessibility, to just fix an issue. On further exploration, I find out that we can just use a hidden label and associate it with the input element using for the attribute. Here the w3 documentation [link](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#hiding-the-label-element).

Comment: `placeholder` is not a replacement for labels. Use labels.

Comment: @Quentin The WCAG [address this subject](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html) and authorize, without encouraging it, the use of a placeholder stating that the label *is not used in such a programmatic sense but is simply referring to a text string in close visual proximity to a component*. This question needs more attention.

Comment: @Quentin I request you to go through the description before downvoting/comment. I have clearly mentioned in the description "What I want is to show placeholders for screen users and hidden labels for screen reader users". And you could have provided much useful comment/answer. Also, I request you to suggest if I can give a better title to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my requirement as I mentioned in the question

> **What I want is to show placeholders for screen users and hidden labels
> for screen reader users.**

The best way is to add a hidden label and associate input element with attribute to the respective label.

```
<label for="search" class="visuallyhidden">Search: </label>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
.visuallyhidden {
      border: 0;
      clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
      height: 1px;
      margin: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
    }
```

Also, you can simply hide the label applying style as `display: none`.

```
<label style={{display: 'none'}} for="search"> Search: </label>
```

You can follow [w3.org document](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#hiding-the-label-element). It's really worth looking at the documentation.

Comment: I don't see how this answers: "Is there a way in which reading placeholder value can be disabled for All screen reader?".

If you provide the `placeholder` attribute value - it still will be announced by some of the screenreaders. So it can lead to announcing similar info twice on input focus. But the solution provided by @Josh looks closer and helps to use the placeholder only as the visual thing

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get creative, you could in theory use JS to manage the placeholder attribute(s). It would slow down the loading of the page somewhat, but you could then remove the placeholder attribute whenever the input receives focus and re-add it when the input loses focus. That would have the effect of disabling the placeholder attribute for assistive technology (at least in interactive forms mode). Sighted visitors probably wouldn't notice the difference. Here's an [example in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81g6fqzb/). I tested in NVDA/Chrome and it worked, but I can't speak for any other screen-reader/browser combinations.

```
// on document load, add the placeholder text
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   myInput.setAttribute("placeholder", myPlaceholder)
});

// when receiving focus, remove the placeholder text
myInput.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
    myInput.removeAttribute("placeholder");
});

// when losing focus, re-add the placeholder text
myInput.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
   myInput.setAttribute("placeholder", myPlaceholder)
});
```

As others have stated, using placeholders is not a suitable replacement for using labels. If you really don't like the look of labels, you can [position them off-screen or use the clip technique](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#techniques) and continue using placeholders. The downside is that some screen readers may read both the label and the placeholder, which isn't ideal, but being overly descriptive is better than being under-descriptive. I would personally be okay with some things being read twice if it only occurs on some browser/screen-reader combinations, and my code is otherwise valid and meets WCAG requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not looking to get something extraordinary.  "What I want is to show placeholders for screen users and hidden labels for screen reader users"  as I explained in question and on further digging I figure out this can be done via adding a hidden label and associate it with for attribute to respective input thanks.

Comment: I thought that your question was asking for "a way in which reading placeholder value can be disabled for All screen reader". I believe that my solution addresses that task.  I'm not sure what it means to "show placeholders for screen users" when most screen reader users are non-sighted visitors.

Comment: This solution addresses disabling the placeholder announcement for the SRs and makes it purely visual. Which quite helpful if you want to make sure that your placeholder will consistently announced  using `aria-labelledby` & `aria-describedby`. Here's the working example - https://playcode.io/1130564

Answer (score 1):

According to [Understanding Success Criterion 2.5.3: Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html)

> As such, in the absence of any other nearby text string (as described in the preceding list), if an input contains placeholder text, such text may be a candidate for Label in Name. This is supported both through the accessible name calculation (discussed later) and from the practical sense that where a visible label is not otherwise provided, **it is likely that a speech-input user may attempt to use the placeholder text value as a means of interacting with the input**.

As long as you do not provide a visual label, the placeholder text is used by assistive technologies (speech-input for instance). Disabling input-assistance to provide more user experience to output-assistance is counter-productive.

You perfectly can use a visual label which emulates the placeholder behaviour when the field is empty (with appropriate precautions to make the fields usable with input assistance once the field is filled).

Comment: This is insightful. Thanks.

Comment: That same paragraph quoted here also states "Note that placeholder text within an input field is not considered an appropriate means of providing a label. The HTML5 specification states 'The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a `<label>`.' ". https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html To the best of my knowledge, the `placeholder` attribute isn't supported by all screen-reader/browser combinations.

Comment: @Josh Yes, that's precisely the question asked. The placeholder emulation I suggest answers this concern and solve any problem with both input and output assistance.

Comment: @Adam - Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer. It seems to me like you're saying that a `placeholder` attribute can be used to label an input field, and assistive technology will use that `placeholder` just like it would a `<label>` element. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Josh No that's quite the opposite approach : users using speech-input assistance should be able to use the visual label (even when the only visual label is a placeholder text). So emulating the `placeholder` behaviour with an accessible label is a better solution than using a native `placeholder` attribute which has low support and is no longer visible when the field is not empty.